# Is it possible to get vectorisation report with g++ or clang++ - openmp

Tags: c++, openmp, vectorization

I want to get the vectorisation report regrading automated vectorisation and openmp SIMD.

Comment: There is `g++ -fopt-info-vec`

Answer (score 3):

```
# gcc
-fopenmp-simd -O3 -ffast-math -march=native -fopt-info-omp-vec-optimized-missed
# clang
-fopenmp-simd -O3 -ffast-math -march=native -Rpass="loop|vect" -Rpass-missed="loop|vect" -Rpass-analysis="loop|vect"
# icc on Linux
-qopenmp-simd -O3 -ffast-math -march=native -qopt-report-file=stdout -qopt-report-format=vs -qopt-report=5 -qopt-report-phase=loop,vec
# msvc
-openmp -O2 -fp:fast -arch:AVX2 -Qvec-report:2
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think Apple's flavor of `clang` supports OpenMP (At least not by default on macOS).

You may find ways to extend it though.

Comment: Clang supports OpenMP. Though Apple's clang does not support it directly, there is a way to make it to generate OpenMP code (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230419/3419533)

Comment: Hi, Well I was talking about Apple's flavor of `clang`. Edited accordingly.