# Force mac to use GCC, not clang

Tags: c, macos, gcc, parallel-processing, clang

I have a program written on Linux in GNU C. The program compiles with GCC. I have an install shell script,

`gcc  -o program program.c -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu11 -lm -fopenmp`

which works greatly.

The problem is with Mac.  For some reason, Mac sees `gcc` and instead uses `clang` even though GCC is installed and install.sh explicitly says `gcc`. `clang` doesn't work with `omp.h` The problem is that clang can't use `omp.h` and solutions offered http://releases.llvm.org/3.7.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#openmp-support don't work, and `omp.h` may not work in mac at all [Enable OpenMP support in clang in Mac OS X (sierra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra)

I never use macs, and because of this nonsense I never plan to.  However, some people using my program want to use Mac, so I have to deal with this.

I've tried various shell script modifications, but none of them work, mac insists on using `clang` and won't use `gcc`

I need to do one of two things which I don't know how to do:

1) force Mac to use `gcc` (which it refuses to do now)

2) get `clang` to use `omp.h` in mac (which from other answers on Stack Overflow, looks impossible)

Comment: You say *"even though GCC is installed"*... where and how did you install it?

Comment: Here is how to force Apple's clang to use OpenMP https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230419/3419533

Answer (score 1):

Your second option (get clang to use omp.h) is not impossible (any more). From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra):

Try using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)'s llvm:

```
brew install llvm
```

You then have all the llvm binaries in `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin`. To compile the [OpenMP Hello World program](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/samples/C/omp_hello.c), for example, type

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib omp_hello.c -o hello
```

You might also have to set the `CPPFLAGS` with `-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include`.